# How to use skewer-mode?

Tags: package, skewer-mode, javascript

I am currently struggling to use skewer-mode in Emacs.

I downloaded and installed skewer-mode via MELPA, so all the dependencies should be inplace.

For testing purposes I even downloaded the `boidsjs` [demo](https://github.com/skeeto/boids-js).

I'll open up `boids.js`, then type <kbd>M-x</kbd>`run-skewer` (opens up the browser with URL `http://127.0.0.1:8080/skewer/demo`) and then finally run <kbd>M-x</kbd>`skewer-mode` (-> skewer-mode enabled).

But in the browser *nothing* happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As I understand it, skewer provides an interface for evaluation of javascript... Do you actually *evaluate* the content of the `boids.js` buffer?

Comment: I'm loading the current buffer with <kbd>C-x C-k</kbd> ("boid.js loaded") and the trying to evaluate with <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>. But it gives me an error that it could not parse the "$"-sign. That is because it did not load the jQuery from the corresponding HTML file (example.html)

Comment: You need to eval the html file in skewer-html-mode.

Comment: How? `C-x C-k` does not work in `skewer-html-mode`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**TLDR;** You have to start the http server ([simple-http](https://github.com/skeeto/emacs-web-server)) and load your HTML files through it.

For example, let's say you have a HTML file named `hello.html` and a JS script file named `script.js` in `/home/user/Documents/javascript` folder.

**hello.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Include skewer.js as a script -->
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/skewer"></script>
    <!-- Include my script.js file -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello world</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**:

```
alert('hey!');
```

**init.el** (or **.emacs**):

```
(require 'simple-httpd)
;; set root folder for httpd server
(setq httpd-root "/home/user/Documents/javascript")
```

It's time to start the server: <kbd>M-x</kbd> `httpd-start`, and open the `index.html` file in the browser, by visiting `http://localhost:8080/hello.html`. You should get the alert in the browser and now call `skwer-repl`.

You can further interact with the browser through the repl. So, everything you evaluate in the repl will be transmitted to the browser. For example if you type `console.log('hey!')` in the repl, you will get this message in the browser's console.

If you want to interactively modify HTML (e.g. live update HTML tags from emacs), add to your 
**init.el** (or **.emacs**):

```
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'skewer-html-mode)
```

Now when you are in your *.html* file you can evaluate tags with <kbd>C-M-x</kbd> (`skewer-html-eval-tag`), and these will be immediately updated in your browser.

Keep in mind that conversely, this also applies to CSS and CSS files.

Comment: This is really great answer, thanks for posting it. Probably also worth nothing that if you don't want to hardcode the `httpd-root` in your config, you can run `M-x eval-expression` `(setq httpd-root "/path/to/files")` from within emacs at any time.

Comment: useless '\' in example html `<script src="http://localhost:8080/skewer"></script>\
` (can't edit - edits must be >=6 characters)

Answer (score 12):

Instead of running the demo, just perform these minimal steps to ensure that everything is working correctly.

1. Open a new buffer with the name myskewer.js
2. Enable JS2-mode (a dependency of skewer)
3. Enable skewer-mode
4. <kbd>M-x</kbd>`run-skewer` (a browser opens, go back to myskewer.js)
5. Type `alert("hello");` and hit <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd> at the end of that line
6. Go back to the browser.

You should see an alert box on the page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Unfortunately, I'm prompted the error "No collapsable element found at point"

Comment: Sorry, My mistake. `C-x C-e` is the actual keys to push. will edit my answer

Comment: That worked!
However: How do I tell Skewer to load the HTML, too? (As shown in the demo)

Comment: @JacksGT Place your downloaded files into `~/public_html` then follow the instructions for "Manual version" at [this](https://github.com/skeeto/skewer-mode#manual-version) link. Once that is done visit http://localhost:8080 in your browser.

Answer (score 2):

In case *port 8080 is already in use*:

you can configure skewer/simple-httpd to use another port by customizing the `httpd-port` variable. (`M-x customize-variable<ret>httpd-port`)

Comment: This tip should be added to the other answers, but really is useful