# Making skewer-repl work on external sites

Tags: web, skewer-mode

skewer-mode works perfectly with their default demo page
(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/skewer/demo`). I'm able to send commands from
`skewer-repl` like `alert('hello world')` and it appears on that particular URL.

Now, how to make the same functionality to work with external sites ?
I have already injected the [greasemonkey
script](https://github.com/skeeto/skewer-mode/blob/master/skewer-everything.user.js)
in the external site but it doesn't seem to work for me. The problem
is that `skewer-repl` seems to only interact with it's demo url:
`http://127.0.0.1:8080/skewer/demo` . Is there a way to make it work
with external sites ?

Comment: You will find some answers -> https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/how-to-use-skewer-mode

Comment: @caisah Thanks, I already saw that. I'm able to work it with the demo url. The problem is I'm not able to make it work with external sites. I think I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: You should add `skewer.js` as a script in your `html` file.

Comment: @caisah Yeah, only if I have access to the server. :)

Comment: One way to debug this might be to open the browser's developer tools and ensuring there no error's occuring

Comment: @IqbalAnsari Thanks, figured that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured this out. Make sure that the following line is present in the greasemonkey script which you inject:

```
// @include /^https?:///
```

That will enable skewering of every site. Now do a refresh of the the
page. Now at the top right hand side of the window (firefox window)
there will be a red triangle. Press on that triangle to inject the
greasemonkey script. You will observe that the color will change from
red to green. Only now, you can start communicating from
`skewer-repl`.

Note: Make sure that you scroll to the top of the page to find the red
triangle, the triangle doesn't move with scrollbar.