# How to use skewer-mode for just html and css

Tags: skewer-mode

I want to use Emacs to create a static website using only HTML and CSS.  I've read through the docs for [skewer-mode](https://github.com/skeeto/skewer-mode) and [simple-httpd](https://github.com/skeeto/emacs-web-server).  It seems simple enough.  There is even this SE post, [how-to-use-skewer-mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/how-to-use-skewer-mode), which details the above steps.  Yet when I follow the post, I just get an "Unable to connect error."  I'm not sure why.

In order to ask an actual question, although I don't know if it's related to my issue, what is meant in the skewer documentation by the following?

> Include "http://localhost:8080/skewer" as a script (see example.html
>   and check your httpd-port)

I don't see how that fits into the bigger picture of how skewer-mode works.  Why doesn't the SE post include that?

Comment: You need to have `<script src="http://localhost:8080/skewer"></script>` in your HTML. It's a script that's used by the browser to receive messages from Emacs.